# Two equivalent definitions of transitive sets

Tags: set-theory

From some lecture notes on set theory I read

$$\forall x \forall y ((x \in y \land y \in A) \rightarrow x \in A)$$

is the definition for a transitive set $A$. But equivalently, we can have

$$\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \subseteq A).$$

I don't see how these two definitions are equivalent. Consider the set $\{1, 2\}$. It would be transitive by the first definition but not transitive by the second definition. When I looked up transitive sets on Wikipedia, I saw the second definition has a condition that $x$ must not be a urelement. However, urelements has not been covered in the lecture notes I am reading so far. Can the counterexample I gave be resolved without treating urelements and sets differently?

Comment: I suspect that the lecture notes you're reading take place in ZF or ZFC, where there are no urelements at all.

Comment: What do you mean by $1$ and $2$ as sets? Usually, $1=\{\emptyset\}$ and $2=\{1\}\cup 1=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}.$ So, $\{1,2\}$ is not transitive in the original sense, since $\emptyset\in 1$ but $\emptyset\not\in\{1,2\}.$

Comment: Yes, the lecture notes only talk about ZF and ZFC, and yes, later in the lecture notes it defines that $1 = \{ \emptyset \}$ and $2 = \{1\}$, but since these definitions comes after the definition of transitive sets, I wonder whether we can show the equivalence without caring about how $1$ and $2$ are defined.

Comment: Write down the definition of $\subseteq$, then simplify the formula.

Comment: Why would the set $\{1,2\}$ be transitive by the first definition? Where is $0$ in that scenario? Is it an element of $\{1,2\}$ somehow?